# Clases en jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

tengo un menu de bootstrap 5  que le he modificado las clases para que tenga distintas visualizaciones dependiendo de la pantalla, en movil lo he dejado abajo fijo y en escritorio lo he dejado a la derecha fuera del canvas.
el codigo hace tu trabajo a la hora de cambiar las clases pero si inspecciono el codigo y cambio de dispositivo no se reflejan los cambios, existe alguna forma  que se limpien los estilos para que cuando cambie de tamaño estos cambios se ejecuten automaticamente y no tenga que refrescar la pagina?

https://pcg.mgconsulting.cl/

este es mi codigo jQuery donde cambie las clases

```
 if (jQuery(window).width() <= 500) { 

 
 } 
 
 if (jQuery(window).width() >=501) { 
   jQuery("#main-nav").removeClass("fixed-bottom");


   jQuery(".offcanvas").removeClass("offcanvas-bottom");
   jQuery(".offcanvas").addClass("offcanvas-end");

   jQuery("#main-nav").addClass("fixed-top");

  

   }
```

codigo html - bootstrap

```
   <nav id="main-nav" class="navbar *fixed-bottom*  navbar-dark 
   bg- primary" aria-labelledby="main-nav-label">




    <div class="offcanvas *offcanvas-bottom* bg-primary" 
    tabindex="-1" id="navbarNavOffcanvas">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar la función `resize()` de **JQuery**. Te permite detectar cuando hay un cambio de tamaño en el layout para ejecutar lo que necesites.

```js
$(function() {
  /* Llamamos a la función cuando carga el DOM, para que evalue el tamaño nada más cargar la página */
  calcularTamanio()
  
  /* Llamamos a la función también cuando ocurre un resize */
  $(window).resize(calcularTamanio);
})

/* Función para hacer una u otra cosa dependiendo del tamaño del dispositivo */
function calcularTamanio() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 500) { 
    console.log('La pantalla es menor o igual a 500px')
  } 

  if ($(window).width() >= 501) {
    console.log('La pantalla es mayor o igual a 501px');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

Se edita para añadir el que el cálculo del tamaño de la ventana también se calcule al recargar la página.

**Referencia:** [resize()](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Comment: Gracias me funciono

Comment: Hola @phpMyGuel  agregue  el código a mi pagina, pero al recargar la pagina me carga mal los estilos

Comment: Porque la comprobación del tamaño de pantalla tienes que hacerla también fuera de la función resize(). Si no lo haces, tan solo se va a aplicar cuando ocurra cambio en el tamaño. Edito la respuesta para reflejar eso.

Comment: Gracias, ahora si funciono